# Eggdrop - TCL Error [wrong # args: should be "proc name args body"]

Tags: tcl, eggdrop

I've made this script which is running under Eggdrop v1.6.21, but I can't get it to start. The error I'm receiving is:

> Tcl error in file 'eggdrop.conf':
>
> wrong # args: should be "proc name args body"
>
> while executing
>
> "proc logit {nick host handle channel text} {

What could be the problem? This is my script.

```
package require mysqltcl

set port {3306}
set host {127.0.0.1}
set user {database_user}
set password {database_password}
set db {database_name}

bind pubm - "*" logit

proc logit {nick uhost handle channel text} {
  global port
  global host
  global user
  global password
  global db

  if {[string match {database_name}} $channel] == 0} {
    set mysql_handler [mysqlconnect -host $host -port $port -user $user -password $password -db $db]
    set sql "insert into irc_feed (nickname, host, message) values ('[mysqlescape $nick]', '[mysqlescape $uhost]', '[mysqlescape $text]')"
    mysqlexec $mysql_handler $sql

    mysqlclose $mysql_handler
  }
}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: I suggest *not* closing this question. While the cause was indeed a simple typographical error, it is a frequently occurring error and the solution may still be helpful (I'm biased, of course).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in the `if` condition: there is an extra `}` after `{database_name}`. It leads to the body of the procedure being closed too early, and the body of the `if` command becomes an unintended extra argument to `proc` (and the very last closing brace becomes an invalid command).

This could be called a parse-time error. If an error makes it all the way to execution (a run-time error) Tcl usually knows enough about the situation to produce a better error message.

At this point though, all the Tcl interpreter knows is that it is trying to execute a command with three arguments, and it has been given four. Hence, the error message is very vague.

However, when a "wrong # args" error is signaled, one has usually either inserted white-space in a place where it shouldn't be, or the braces don't match up. A brace-matching editor is very useful in the latter case.

Comment: Perfect! That's solved it. Can't believe I overlooked that.